# truffle | balanceOf return octal number

Tags: solidity, blockchain, truffle

I wrote my erc20 token by solidity and the decimals of token is 18. 
I'm testing the smart contract on truffle and one thing that I noticed was the octal number is returned when I called the `balanceOf()` function. 
I want to check the balance of accounts as decimals which is fixed as 18.
For example, I want to transfer the `1.001` or `22.0000003`  and then get the return value of `balanceOf()` as `23.0010003`.
However, this is the result I got.

```
> cc.transfer(user1, 000000000000000100, {from: owner})
{ [String: '512'] s: 1, e: 2, c: [ 512 ] }
```

How can I transfer or check the balance as fixed 18 Decimals not the octal number? Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, a leading zero indicates an octal number.

Just don't include the leading zeros. Use `100`.

Comment: I get it. When I call `balanceOf()` function on Remix, it returned the number like `10010000000000000100123`. The actual balance is `10010.000000000000100123`. I was confused! Thanks a lot!!